# A alteração de valor no array de inteiro em um índice funciona em um caso, e em outro não, por quê?

Tags: c#, array, winforms, random

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   private void btnRodaLabirinto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[,] Lab = new char[10, 10];
        int[,] Lab2 = new int[10, 10];
        int I = 0, J = 0;
        Random NumerosRandomicos = new Random();

        //abaixo, setando labirinto com 0 e 1
        for (I = 0; I < 10; I++)
        {
            for (J = 0; J < 10; J++)
            {
                Lab2[I, J] = NumerosRandomicos.Next(0, 2);
                if (I == 9 && J == 9) Lab2[I, J] = 3;
                if (I == 0 && J == 0) Lab2[I, J] = 3;
            }
        }

        //Printando na Texbox
        for (I = 0; I < 10; I++)
        {
            for (J = 0; J < 10; J++)
            {
                txtLabirinto.Text = txtLabirinto.Text +
                    Convert.ToString(Lab2[I, J]).ToString();
            }
            txtLabirinto.AppendText("\r\n");
        }

    }
```

Já fiz fora do for, assim:

```
   I = 0;
   J = 0;
   Lab2[I, J] = 3;
```

Porém sem sucesso também, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: o código funciona corretamente! qual é o erro? Exemplo rodando: https://ideone.com/mWYb6K (apesar de uma conversão mau feita)

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona? Só uma dica, em C# usamos outro padrão de nomenclatura, em geral variáveis tem nomes iniciando por minúsculas

Comment: A posição 0,0 que tem um if para ser setado 3, esta sendo aleatório (0 ou 1). Já a posição 9,9 que tem um if para ser setado 3 também, está funcionando

Comment: @BraianFreitas eu fiz até um exemplo: https://ideone.com/mWYb6K e isso que você disse de setar para 3 acontece nas duas posições, apesar que o código deve ser melhorado mas, o que é pra ser feito acontece sim

Comment: Entendo, talvez eu esteja cometendo um erro, porque anexei uma foto a pergunta do resultado que estou obtendo

Comment: @BraianFreitas eu rodei em um form e funcionou seu código! não tem problema algum!

Comment: Entendi, mas obrigado pela solução (não sei porque no meu winform não tá funcionando), aqui tá mostrando o resultado da foto, rodei como aplicativo de console e funcionou, sei lá, vou sentar e chorar aqui

Comment: Resolvi o problema, a Textbox (essa da foto q enviei) estava pequena, aumentei o tamanho e resolveu